# Add More Product Data to Search Results Page

Tags: event-observer, product-list, catalogsearch

I'm shooting to add some additional information (below the price, in the template) to products on my search results page only. This data is not available to the price.phtml template, as it is never loaded into the collection. What I need to do is get to that search results page product collection, and add a few more selects. I was hoping there would be an after_collection event to observe, but I found none being fired that looked at all useful. I perused catalogsearch, but became confused and frustrated, as Magento often makes me feel. If someone knows where this collection is coming from and how to hook into it and modify it, that would be extremely helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Have you browsed app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Results.php & check at the end of app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php as there seems to be the global advanced search collection..

Comment: ...and keep in mind that if you wish to mod these files you should extend them in a module or **recreate the paths & file(s) but under the app/code/local**